# Debian не уходит в спящий режим

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Ноутбук HP Pavilion dv3000, стоит debian 8. При попытке уйти в спящий режим дублируются следующие сообщения:

```
Freezing of tasks failed after 20.00 seconds (0 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=1)
```

Comment: Загляните в  логи `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`, `dmesg`.Скорей всего, там есть подробности. Смотрите по слову `Freezing`.

Comment: pm-suspend.log - такого файла в папке log нет.  В dmesg: (Nothing has been logged yet.)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как это связано, но проблема решилась удалением из автозагрузки скрипта, запускающего xflux.